# How to filter traffic by Client IP with istio on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, traffic, istio-gateway

I'm trying to make a traffic management in my k8s cluster with istio

My goal to achieve is looking like this:

I have *2 versions* of my application running, V1 and V2. I want to make sure that **all** traffic that comes to the domain - *istio-ingress LoadBalancer IP* was going to V1 and the traffic that comes from the selected IP addresses (Whitelist) should be directed to V2 for testing purposes
I Was trying to achieve it like this and in many other ways, but didn't succeed, hope for your help and directions where to look

I've tried EnvoyFilter with Gateway and VirtualService but it seems like LUA is incorrect and I can't figure it why. Also I can't seem to find anywhere if istio-ingress sees my REAL client ip or not. Expected it to add header based on my IP and with that header by matching rules redirect me to correct version of the service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-by-ip
  namespace: sn-backend
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                print("Processing request")
                local client_ip = request_handle:headers():get("x-forwarded-for")
                request_handle:logInfo("Client IP: " .. client_ip)
                if client_ip == "<REDUCTED_IP>" then
                  request_handle:logInfo("Adding header for IP: " .. client_ip)
                  request_handle:headers():add("x-destination-version", "v2")
                end
              end
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-router
  namespace: sn-backend
spec:
  hosts:
    - "domain.example.com"
  gateways:
    - httpbin-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - headers:
            x-destination-version:
              exact: "v2"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: httpbin1.sn-backend.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8000
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: httpbin.sn-backend.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8000
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: httpbin-gateway
  namespace: sn-backend
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "domain.example.com"
```

Comment: Please ensure the clientip is captured using proxy protocol.  Also ensure proper value is set for xff_num_trusted_hops to get proper client ip if there more components between the client and ingress gateway for ex: extra load balancers, waf etc.

Comment: Thanks for your Response @NatarajMedayhal Problem is that I can't figure out how to properly capture it that's why I'm here. No components between client and ingress. GCP assigned external ip for my load balancer ingress and that's it

Comment: Please refer following istio documentation for maintaining client ip by enabling proxy protocol.  https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/#proxy-protocol  Also refer GCP documentation https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp#proxy-protocol

Comment: To get the actual real client IP, make sure you set the `externalTrafficPolicy` : `Local` in the Istio ingress GW deployment (check the docs [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#network)). You might not even need a Lua script - you can do a match on `x-forwarded-for` header directly for the IP (depending on how many IPs you're trying to do this for). You should also turn on the Lua logging and just write out the IP to make sure you're getting the right onw.